# How to send it all one request in Hibernate ? (HQL)

Tags: java, hibernate

```
getSession()
            .createQuery(
                    "UPDATE Friend SET status = :status, actionUserId = :userId, lastModifyDate = :lastModifyDate WHERE userId = :userId AND friendId = :idUserFriend")
            .setParameter("status", Integer.valueOf(InviteFriendState.CANCEL.getState()))
            .setParameter("userId", userId).setParameter("idUserFriend", idUserFriend)
            .setParameter("lastModifyDate", new Date()).executeUpdate();
}getSession()
            .createQuery(
                    "UPDATE Friend SET status = :status, actionUserId = :userId, lastModifyDate = :lastModifyDate WHERE userId = :idUserFriend AND friendId = :userId ")
            .setParameter("status", Integer.valueOf(InviteFriendState.CANCEL.getState()))
            .setParameter("userId", userId).setParameter("idUserFriend", idUserFriend)
            .setParameter("lastModifyDate", new Date()).executeUpdate();
}`
```

How to send it all one request in Hibernate ? (HQL)

How to combine a request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why doing two requests ? 
You can do the same thing with a single query by adding an OR condition :

```
getSession()
            .createQuery(
                    "UPDATE Friend SET status = :status, actionUserId = :userId, lastModifyDate = :lastModifyDate 
              WHERE (userId = :userId AND friendId = :idUserFriend)
              ||    (userId = :idUserFriend AND friendId = :userId)  ")
            .setParameter("status", Integer.valueOf(InviteFriendState.CANCEL.getState()))
            .setParameter("userId", userId).setParameter("idUserFriend", idUserFriend)
            .setParameter("lastModifyDate", new Date()).executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: It's also important to understand that while the user may issue multiple `UPDATE` statements, Hibernate will likely batch these if they're being issued inside the same transaction, so they're technically being pushed to the database within the context of the same transaction, so they happen atomically regardless.

Comment: Of course, but it is not its case since the job can be done in one request. It is not useful to give a complex answer for addressing a simple problem.